# Set QTableWidget cell's borders to 0px

Tags: qt, qt4

How can I set the cell borders in a QTableWidget to 0px? Preferably I can choose which sides of a cell's border to set to 0, but I can live with setting them all to 0 as well.

EDIT: Either setting the border to 0px or setting the color to white would be good as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can disable all the borders with `QTableWidget::setShowGrid`, and re-enable some of them with a style sheet (for instance: `"QTableView::item { border-left: 1px solid black; }"`)

The latter are cell interior borders, so they might not be as well aligned as the grid.

If you want to change the borders individually for each cell, you need to write a delegate (like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262318/how-do-i-assign-a-border-to-a-specific-qtablewidgetitem-or-a-row-in-a-qtablewidge/7264248#7264248)).

Answer (score 10):

check if QTableWidget's [setShowGrid](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qtableview.html#showGrid-prop) would work for you, smth like this:

```
tableWidget->setShowGrid(false);
```

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it for me without affecting widget's focus policy and using qss is to create the following custom delegate and install it for table:

***.h:**

```
class FocusControlDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    public:
        FocusControlDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
        virtual void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const;        
        void setFocusBorderEnabled(bool enabled);

    protected:
        bool f_focus_border_enabled;
    };
```

***.cpp:**

```
FocusControlDelegate::FocusControlDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {
    f_focus_border_enabled = false;
}

void FocusControlDelegate::setFocusBorderEnabled(bool enabled) {
    f_focus_border_enabled = enabled;
}

void FocusControlDelegate::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
    if(!f_focus_border_enabled && option->state & QStyle::State_HasFocus)
        option->state = option->state & ~QStyle::State_HasFocus;
}
```