# Sudoku GUI using QTableView (QT5)

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5, qtableview

I'm trying to create a GUI for sudoku (for improving my QT5 skills).  I have decided to use for these purposes a QTableView. Up until that point there is no problem.

[image]

Now i want to draw grids to make 3x3 fields more visible. Is there any ideas, how i can do that?

Comment: [Might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262318/how-do-i-assign-a-border-to-a-specific-qtablewidgetitem-or-a-row-in-a-qtablewidg)

Comment: Gosh, please, you've found a hammer and now everything looks like a nail to you? Create a custom widget for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really recommend not using a `QTableView` for this, it's potentially solvable by using delegates (which are mostly for data presentation) but it would be very tricky. The best solution would be for you to build a custom widget by subclassing `QWidget`, building the `paintEvent` functionality and putting a data model in place. I know that building a custom widget certainly sounds more difficult, but it's actually quite simple.

Here's some good resources to get started with:

- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405227
- http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/customwidget/
- http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/designer-customwidgetplugin/
- http://qt.developpez.com/tutoriels/braindeadbzh/customwindow/

After that the `QPainter` class reference will be very useful to implement your drawing commands.